# Publisher Action without Publishing to Chatter

Tags: publisher, chatter-feed, action

Good afternoon all,

Is it possible to enable the log-a-call publisher action but not post to chatter?  I want the publisher action to create a log-a-call record but I don't want it to create a post on chatter.   I like the publisher action log-a-call UI but want to keep the feed for other posts.

Thanks!

Pziggity